# 2 decimals in JavaScript with out regular expression and without rounding the numbers

Tags: javascript

Can anyone give me the code for accepting only 2 decimals using JavaScript.
**Without regular expression and without jQuery**.
The number should not be round.

Answer (score 2):

## [To Fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

use `toFixed(2);`  for doing that

```
var num = 2.4;
alert(num.toFixed(2));  will alert 2.40
```

Comment: thanks , but wen iam using toFixed() method then number is rounding and iam getting the values dynamically(what is user entered).

Comment: @SimSam give me some no's example, i am sure we can find an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
parseFloat(Math.round(yourNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

> The number should not be round.

Use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to round down and you can use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to generically set the number of digits.

```
function trimDP(x, i) {
    var e = Math.pow(10, i || 0);
    return Math.floor(e * x) / e;
}
trimDP(2.45991, 2); // 2.45
```

If you want this as a *String*, you need to use `.toFixed(i)` **after** so that it doesn't get rounded.

```
var x = trimDP(2.40001, 2); // 2.4
x.toString(2); // "2.40"
```